# Taking data from website such as most recent blog and use it in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web

I am a new developer and have a client who wants to have a view with a most recent blog. I really have no idea on how to take information from a website, but i definitely want to learn how to do this. I'm not sure on how to approach this. The client has a mobile website so would it be practical to just use a web view? Will the client need to be change their website for me to pull the most recent blog and other things. Is it difficult to take the information from the website?

Comment: Do they have web services to get blog data? you may run the possibility that your app will get rejected if it functions are limited...

Comment: You'll want to first check if part (or all) of it is available in an RSS feed. You can then use something like RestKit to grab the data and store it. If it's partially there (or not there at all) you'll then need to present the rest in a UIWebView.

Comment: The guy just types out everything with no rss... is it still possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check out teamtreehouse website. They have a course called "Build a Blog Reader iPhone App" It will teach you all the basics of how to pull data using JSON and display it in tableView.

Answer (score 0):

The blog probably has an RSS feed. You can pull that RSS feed using [`MWFeedParser`](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) and put it into a `UITableView`

Comment: The guy just types out everything with no rss... is it still possible to accomplish this?